# import.io - can i extract multiple tables data

Tags: import.io

Can I use connector to extract data from two (multiple) tables on a web page ? I don't want to configure two different connectors for each table on the same page.

Comment: Can you share the URL?  It might be possible to train the connector to both tables.

Comment: URL is  - http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/powergenerationdistribution/suzlonenergy/SE17   when you click on expand all (+), it will show you multiple tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can train your extractor as "Single row", so you create a column for each piece of data you want from the page. That way you can get all you need, independently of where it is (or in which table it is).